# What happens if two resources differ only in their extension in andorid?

Tags: android

I have a small confusion, when in drawable folder in android i try to copy same file it says that "Resource with this name already exists" which is absolutely correct. Again if try to copy an image with different .extension but with same file name it takes it. But in R.java file only 1 resource id is generated. What does this mean? Also ID will point to which resource?

Comment: May I suggest you to **use different names**?

Comment: I do understand that I should use different names, perfectly fine. Just out of curiosity I wanted to know why this behavior is shown ? or what is actually happening behind the scene ?

Comment: Test it and find out. I doubt there's a standard. In fact, a different IDE may very well not let you do that.

Comment: I wouldn't even ask myself what does it do if I behave incorrectly, since I don't. Not consciously, at least.

Comment: Yeah, my IDE does not like that, and fails to build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It simply means that at the time of compilation it is only able to generate id from one of the available resource. Why can't it generate both id's if it has allowed to keep both resources in the same folder? Because for each resource, there is a static integer named after the **name of file, excluding extension** so naturally, there can't be more than one of these static integers in one file. 
ID points to which resource? I think you can't be sure. I just checked by recreating the scenario (out of curiosity) and I found that it pointed to the resource I added in the end!

Still, it is irrelevant as to which resource it points to. Because it won't allow to run the app.

P.S: If you really want to use resources with same name (diff extension) then you can do so by using **assets**